# Combining Date and Time into DateTime with Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having a hard time with Date and Time objects in Javascript.

Starting from a CSV file, it contains the values "12/3/2019" and "14:00:00" in two different cells and I'm importing those values with `SpreadsheetApp.open()` for the CSV-file.

It now seems the Date Object has the desired date, with a wrong time (11:00 instead of 14:00). However, the Date Object for the time (14:00:00) get's wrong:

If `time` is set to the value "14:00" imported by the `SpreadsheetApp.open()` command, the following command

```
  new Date ( time )
```

yields something very weird: `12/31/1969 13:00:00`.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to combines both date and time object into something which can then be used by the `CreateEvent()` command?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the string to the constructor of the built-in **'Date'** object, the parameter must be in the format readable to the **Date.parse()** method. Therefore, if your plan is to parse dates from strings, construct the resulting string using the following template

```
2011-10-10T14:48:00
```

where 'T' is the delimiter. [More on the Date object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Here's the example of building the template string. You could use **Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, format)** as a shortcut but this is how you build the template step by step:

```
   var d = new Date();

  //Date template
  var template = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss";

  //Year
  template = template.replace("YYYY", d.getFullYear());

  //Month. Add leading zero if required.
  template =  template.replace('MM', ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2));

  //Date. Add leading zero if required.
  template = template.replace('DD', ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2));

  //Hours
  template = template.replace('HH', ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2));

  //Minutes
  template = template.replace('mm', ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2));

  //Seconds
  template = template.replace('ss', ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2));

  Logger.log(template);

  var anotherDate = new Date(template);
```